# How to get last id for relationships in a transaction between models in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, transactions, last-insert-id

I have this code inside a function in user-controller. I'm, using Codeigniter.

```
$name_user = $this->input->post('contact-company');

$company_name = $this->input->post('name-company');
$company_orgnr = $this->input->post('orgnr-company');
$phone_company = $this->input->post('phone-company');
$email_company = $this->input->post('email-company');

//Insert a a new user                        
$user_info = array(
                'username'  => $email_company,
                'name_user' => $name_user
            );
$company_info = array(
                'name' => $company_name,
                'orgnr' => $company_orgnr,
                'phone' => $phone_company,
                'email' => $email_company
            );

//Insert a new user in db
$query_insertuser = "START TRANSACTION";

//Get sql for inserting a new user
$um = new Usermodel();
$query_insertuser .= $um->getSQLInsert($user_info);

//Get sql for inserting a new company
$cm = new Companymodel();
$query_insertuser .= $cm->getSQLInsert($company_info);

//Get sql for inserting relation between user
//and company (How do I get ID of user and ID of company to use?)
$upm = new Userprofilemodel();
$query_insertuser .= $upm->getSQLInsert();

$query_insertuser .= "COMMIT";

//Do the atual insert
$um->insert($query_insertuser);
```

It's used for handling a registration through a form. (Validation is done through the form-validation libray)-

- Users with username, name_user is stored in a users-table
- Companies are stored in a companies-table
- Relations between companies and users are stored in a
  userprofile-table

I think the code is kind of self-explainatory, but **I'm not clear in how to insert the relation in the userprofile-model**. I do need the last inserted id for user and the last inserted id for company, but in my code I don't have that because I don't actually insert any users or companies before calling `$upm->getSQLInsert();`

Or am I doing this incorrectly? Please give me any pointers...

Answer (score 0):

**I was obviously not doing this correctly.** In case anyone care to bother this is my solution:-)

**User-controller** (part of it)

```
//Insert a new user in db
$um = new Usermodel();

$um->startTransaction();                        
$user_id = $um->insert($user_info);

$cm = new Companymodel();
$company_id = $cm->insert($company_info);

//Insert a new user-profile for newly inserted user
$upm = new Userprofilemodel();
$userprofile_info = array(
                    'user_id' => $user_id,
                    'company_id' => $company_id
                );                        
$upm->insert($userprofile_info);                        
$um->endTransaction();
```

**User-model** (part of it)

```
public function startTransaction() {
        $this->db->trans_start();
}

public function endTransaction() {
        $this->db->trans_complete();
}

public function insert(array $user_info) {
    $this->db->insert('user', $user_info); 
    return $this->db->insert_id();
}
```

**Company-model** (part of it)

```
public function insert(array $company_info) {
    $this->db->insert('company', $company_info); 
    return $this->db->insert_id();
}
```

**Userprofile-model** (part of it)

```
public function insert(array $userprofile_info) {
    $this->db->insert('user_profile', $userprofile_info); 
    return $this->db->insert_id();
}
```